# Oracle apex logged user “info pge”

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have a table called SYSUSER Contains( User_ID, User_Password, User_Type) when the user logged into the page by his user id and password I want display the information of that user only not others users. User_type are : student and instructor.
Is there any idea how can I do this problem if there is a query or anything else

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

In a Classic Report (or however you want to display the information), try a query like this:

```
select * from SYSUSER where user_id = :APP_USER;
```

APEX will substitute the APP_USER bind variable with the user you are logged in as .